# Javascript merge array if there is duplicate value

Tags: javascript

var arr = [[7, 50], [7, 60], [8, 40]];

how to merge this array to become the result like this ?
[[7, 110], [8,40]];

lets say if i have over hundreds of these smaller arrays wrapped by an array

Comment: do a bubble sort and loop through it :P

Answer (score 5):

I recommend that you use a map to store the results rather than an array. Here is a O(n) solution:

```
var arr = [[7,50], [7,60], [8,40]];

function merge_array(arr) {
    var map = {};
    for (var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        if (arr[i][0] in map) {
            map[arr[i][0]] += arr[i][1];
        } else {
            map[arr[i][0]] = arr[i][1];
        }
    }

    return map;
}
```

And if you are dead set on an array as output, you can then convert it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the O(n) solution with an array result:

```
function merge(arr){  

    var map = {};
    var key;

    //Constructing the map
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++ ) {
      key = arr[i][0];
      if ( typeof map[key] != 'undefined' ){
        map[key] += arr[i][1];
      } else {
        map[key] = arr[i][1];
      }
    }

    //Converting the map to an array
    var result = [];
    for ( key in map ){
       result.push( [key, map[key]] );
    } 

    return result;    
}
```